# Can I do solana spl-token authorize mint --disable but from javascript?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I am trying create an NFT mint, I know how to do it from CLI, but I need to do it from JS, I am looking at the code of @solana/spl-token package, but cannot find API analogous to

```
spl-token authorize <TOKEN_ID> mint --disable
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can!  Here's some code that doesn't compile to get you started:

```
import { Connection, PublicKey, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { AuthorityType, setAuthority } from '@solana/spl-token';

const mint = new PublicKey("mint in base 58");
const payer = new Keypair(...);
const mintAuthority = new Keypair(...);
const connection = new Connection
await setAuthority(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    mintAuthority,
    AuthorityType.MintTokens,
    null, // this sets the mint authority to null
);
```

Adapted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/7c7507f4ec1f320bbc33af459d4d8b5573a6a906/token/js/test/e2e/setAuthority.test.ts#L88